# Dijkstra without Comparable Node Java

Tags: java, debugging, dijkstra, comparable

thats the first question i ask here, so if there's sth I did wrong: please comment :)

I've got an annoying project to finish. I must implement a Dijkstra algorithm for a node start to a node end. The Graph is weighted by the length of the edges that connect the nodes. One problem is that the Graph, Edge and Node classes don't implement Comparable, the node class doesn't contain sth. like weigth of node or the pervious node. I'm not allowed to change anything in Node, Graph oder Edge class.

So I tried to implement Dijkstra by using a private class in my "RoutingAlgoritm" that contains distance, previous node etc.

Anyway, now I've got the problem that my target node doesn't get a previous node and i've got no idea why. I hope you can help me.

```
    private List<Node> dijkstra( Graph g, NodeForDijkstra start, NodeForDijkstra target, TravelType tt) throws NoSuchRouteException{
    PriorityQueue<NodeForDijkstra> q = new PriorityQueue<NodeForDijkstra>();
    start.distance = 0.;
    start.prev = null;
    ArrayList<Node> explored = new ArrayList<Node>();
    q.add( start );
    if( q.isEmpty() ){
        throw new NoSuchRouteException();
    }
    while( !q.isEmpty() ){
        NodeForDijkstra n = q.poll();
        Node v = n.getNode;
        if( v.getId() == target.getNode.getId() ){
            return path(target);
        }
        explored.add( v );
        for( Edge e : v ){
            if( e.allowsTravelType(tt, Direction.FORWARD) ){
                Node puf = e.getEnd();
                NodeForDijkstra newNode = new NodeForDijkstra(puf);
                double newdist = n.distance + e.getLength(); 
                if( !explored.contains(puf) ){
                    newNode.prev = n;
                    System.out.println( newNode.getNode.getId()+ " | " + newNode.prev.getNode.getId() );
                    if( !q.contains( newNode ) ){
                        newNode.distance = newdist;
                        q.add(newNode);
                    }else if( newNode.distance > newdist ){
                        System.out.println( "foo" );
                        q.remove(n);
                        newNode.distance = newdist;
                        q.add(newNode);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return path(target);
}

private List<Node> path( NodeForDijkstra target ){
    List<Node> path = new ArrayList<Node>();
    for( NodeForDijkstra n = target; n!= null; n = n.prev ){
        path.add( n.getNode );
        System.out.println(n.getNode.getId());
        System.out.println( "bar" );
    }
    Collections.reverse(path);
    return path;
}

private class NodeForDijkstra implements Comparable<NodeForDijkstra>{

    public double distance = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
    public Node getNode;
    public NodeForDijkstra prev = null;

    public NodeForDijkstra( Node n ) {
        this.getNode = n;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(NodeForDijkstra o) {
        return Double.compare(distance, o.distance);
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "your target node doesn't get a previous node"?  If there's a statement that doesn't do what you expect, it would help if you point out what the statement is, what you were hoping it would do, and what it's doing instead.  Without that, it's difficult for us to understand exactly what your problem is.

Comment: what i mean by that ist that the previous node of my target stays null